Why does my C program with any input results in segmentation fault?
I've spent hours of racking my brain on why doesn't this work
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int getLine(char s[], int lim);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);
void add(char to[], char from[], int max);

int main(){
  int len;
  int max;
  char line[MAXLINE];
  char longest[MAXLINE];

  max = 0;
  len = 0;
  while(( len = getLine(line, MAXLINE)) > 0){
    
    if(max == len){
      add(longest, line, max);
    }

    if (len > max){
      max = len;
      copy(longest, line);
    }
  }
  
  if (max > 0){ 
    printf("%s", longest);
  }
  return 0;
}
int getLine(char s[], int lim){
  int c, i;
  
  for (int state = FALSE, i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n';){
    if(c == '\t' || c == ' ' && state == TRUE)
      continue;

    if (c == '\t' || c == ' '){
      s[i] = c;
      ++i;
      state = TRUE;
    } else {
      s[i] = c;
      state = FALSE;
      ++i;
    }
  }
  if (c == '\n'){
    s[i] = c;
    ++i;
  }
  s[i] = '\0';

  return i;
}

void copy(char to[], char from[]){
  int i = 0;

  while((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0'){
    ++i;
  }
}

void add(char to[], char from[], int max){
  if (max != 0){
    int control = max * 2;
    to[max] = from[0];
    ++max;
    for(int i = 1; max <= control; ++max, ++i ){
      to[max] = from[i];
    };
  };
}

Am I missing something ? I ran valgrind with this results

==22786== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22786== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22786== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22786== Command: ./maxLine
==22786==
as
==22786== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==22786==    at 0x10933A: getLine
==22786==    by 0x109230: main
==22786==
==22786== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==22786==    at 0x10934D: getLine
==22786==    by 0x109230: main
==22786==
==22786== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==22786==    at 0x10923E: main
==22786==
==22786== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==22786==    at 0x1091C9: main
==22786==
==22786== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==22786==    at 0x1091F6: main
==22786==
==22786== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==22786==    at 0x109396: copy
==22786==    by 0x10921C: main
==22786==

In gdb :

[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
as
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555555533a in getLine (s=0x7fffffffd7e0 "as\377\367\377\177", lim=1000) at maxLine.c:53
53        s[i] = c;
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x000055555555533a in getLine (s=0x7fffffffd7e0 "as\377\367\377\177", lim=1000) at maxLine.c:53
#1  0x0000555555555231 in main () at maxLine.c:18

I don't know where to start

One extra note, in addition to the answer given, it that c == '\t' || c == ' ' && state == TRUE looks like you may want to add parentheses to fix precedence, if you want STATE to be relevant to tabs too.

When requesting debugging help, provide a [mre], including an exact copy of input that reproduces the problem. “Any input” is not a suitable description. You may have tried various values for some forms of input suitable to the program, but somebody else coming to your program for the first time may not know what form of input is suitable for the program. And having a specific concrete example helps debugging and communication about the program.

valgrind and gdb will be more helpful if you recompile the program with -g -Og added to the command line.

In getline,  for (int state = FALSE, i = 0; … declares an i that exists only during execution of the for statement. The value of the i declared earlier in the routine is not affected. That earlier i is uninitialized. That earlier i is used later in the routine without having been initialized.
Most compilers would diagnose this. Compile with warnings enabled and elevated to errors. With Clang, start with -Wmost -Werror. With GCC, start with -Wall -Werror. With MSVC, start with /W3 /WX.
There may be other errors in the program.
